# Google Cloud Storage auth problems

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am having problems in the authentication of an account in Google Cloud. I had an account (test_account@gmail.com) which I used to make different tests with Google Storage. Now that I learnt, I want to do different things with another account (new_account@gmail.com).

I changed the active account with `` gcloud config set account `new_account@gmail.com` ``  and I removed the old account with `gcloud auth revoke test_account@gmail.com`. When I check the active accounts I get:

```
>gcloud auth list
     Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       new_account@gmail.com
```

I login with the command `gcloud auth login` and I get no problems.

That's why I suppose that everything is right. But when I execute the code that I wanted I get an error saying that the old account (test_account@gmail.com) has not access to a specific bucket that I am using. That's correct because I removed the access for that old account to the bucket, but I don't understand why I'm still operating with that account after all the changes I made.

This is the exact error I'm getting:

```
"code": 403,\n    "message": "test_account@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": "test_account@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object."
```

Does anyone encounter the same error? I don't know what else to do. I also checked this as google cloud documentation recommends:

```
>gsutil version -l

gsutil version: 5.6
boto version: 2.49.0
python version: 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
OS: Windows 10
multiprocessing available: False
using cloud sdk: True
pass cloud sdk credentials to gsutil: True
config path(s): C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\legacy_credentials\new_account@gmail.com\.boto
gsutil path: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gsutil
compiled crcmod: True
installed via package manager: False
editable install: False
```

And there is no signs of the old account anywhere. Hope someone can help me identifying where the error is, or why the command `gsutil` is saving the old account somewhere so I can erase it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you specified a separate credential file in your code or are you using the default application credentials provided by the Cloud SDK? If the later it is possible that your old account is still used as a default in the file `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`.

You can change this with the following command:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login

Comment: You're welcome. Can you marked this question as solved? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow#:~:text=Click%20the%20green%20outlined%20checkmark,solution%2C%20and%20then%20accept%20that.